# How to check if a cell is empty (Excel\VisualC#)

Tags: c#, excel, cell

My aim is to check line per line in the `Sheet1` in order to discover how many rows are, so i put a do\while that should stop once it reaches a blank cell

Example:

> row1 data
>  row2 data
>  row3 data
> row4 data
> row5 data
>
> row6 data
>   row7 data

In this case I need only the first 5 rows, so the do\while check is intended to stop once it reaches the blank cell. This doesn't happens, because the check doesn't loop (it stops after completing a circle like it finds a blank cell even if it is filled with data).

```
string str;
int rCnt = 11; //the data I need is after the 10th row in excel
int cCnt = 1;
int valori = 1;

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(label4.Text, 0, false, 5, "", "", 
                                                 false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, 
                                                 "", true, false, 0, true, false, 
                                                 false);
Excel.Sheets xlsheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
string sheet1 = "Sheet1";
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlsheet.get_Item(sheet1);
Excel.Range xlCell;   

do
{
    rCnt++;
    str = "A" + rCnt;
    xlCell = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.get_Range(str, str);
} while (xlCell.Value2 == null);
```

I tried changing `Value2` to `Value` or `Text` and trying to set == "" instead of null.

Comment: you can use string.NullorEmpty method

Comment: I tried "while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xlCell.Value2));" but it returns this error: The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 4):

If you want the loop stop when reach blank cell then .. Try to change

```
while (xlCell.Value2 == null);
```

with

```
while (! IsNull(xlCell.Value2));
```

Comment: I tried this too, but it seems it doesn't recognize "IsDBNull" word.
Is there something I have to add?

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to check a cell is empty:

```
 if (sheet.Cells[4,3] == null || sheet.Cells[4,3].Value2 == null || sheet.Cells[4,3].Value2.ToString() == "")
   MessageBox.Show(“cell on row 4 col 3 is empty”);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Text` property of the selected cell. It can be converted to a string type via "as". The result string can already be checked as usual in C#, like not-empty

```
string TempText = excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Text as string;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TempText)){
// actions
}
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Comment: Careful using `Text` for at times it may have the text of "#####" instead of the value being sought. Better to use `Value2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue mainly comes from when you don't know what sort of data to expect. When I work with Excel reads I often do something similar to:

```
var _cell = range.Cells[1, 2].Value2;
if (_cell.GetType() != typeof(Double))
```

In your instance if you always are getting a string returned then you should be able to assume the cast:

```
string _str = (string)(range.Cells[str, str] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

and then check that is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

using `Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` to read excelsheet:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[2];

Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;
string wwdEmpty = Convert.ToString(excelRange.Cells[5, 14].value2);
// this is working code with NULL Excell cell
```

Comment: This is not proper code formatting. Please refer to the [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) documentation, which outlines how to format code using indents and/or code fences.

Answer (score -1):

```
do
{
    rCnt++;
    str = Sheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Value;
} while (str != null);
```

Comment: Sheet is defined as 
        Excel._Worksheet Sheet; 
and it represent your sheet in excel workbook

Comment: A bit of explanation in your answer would be helpful? Consider editing your answer (click the "edit" link)