# How do you check what cells within a range of a columns in Excel are empty using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to check which cells in a column range for e.g. D2:D8 are empty & in the 1st empty cell, write string data into that cell.

I've seen lots of code showing how to check the last not empty cell, but nothing within a certain range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an Excel Range is empty in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854491/how-to-check-if-an-excel-range-is-empty-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Have you considered looking at something like this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123562/how-to-check-if-a-cell-is-empty-excel-visualc

P.S. Please post any code you currently have so we can help in modifying it if necessary, although I think the answer is in the link I shared.